# How can I create a view where each row in one table is treated as a child of each row in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to create a view which that combines two tables to have the form below.

**Table A (column FIRST)**

```sql
FIRST
-----
A
B
C
```

**Table B (column SECOND)**

```sql
SECOND
-----
1
2
3
```

**Result**

```sql
FIRST | SECOND
------|-------
A     | 1
A     | 2
A     | 3
B     | 1
B     | 2
B     | 3
C     | 1
C     | 2
C     | 3
```

I have been struggling to wrap my brain around this one. Something like the below code is what I would like to end up with for my view, to make it similar to my other views, but all the options I've tried haven't worked quite right.

```sql
SELECT
    FIRST,
    '' AS SECOND
FROM Table A

UNION ALL

SELECT
    '' AS FIRST,
    SECOND
FROM Table B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a `cross join`:

```
select a.first, b.second
from a cross join
     b
order by a.first, b.second;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CROSS JOIN. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS 
SELECT a.first, b.second
FROM tablea a
CROSS JOIN tableb b
```